# Bootstrap hamburger no longer appears after modifying colors

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am fairly new to html, css, js and bootstrap 4.  I am trying to build a website just to practice my skills.  I finally managed to change the colors, text, font-size etc of my bootstrap 4 navbar, however not when I scale down, the hamburger symbol disappears and I lose my  options.

The only bit of code I removed was the bg-light to change the color, as well as create a custom class on my  to change text color

a link to my code: https://codepen.io/jehc10/pen/LKqRRQ

```
             .navbar-nav {
              background:#4287f5;
              }

              .navbar-brand {
               background:#4287f5;
                     }

                .navbar-brand.custom{
                  color:#FFFFFF;
                   font-size:25px
                  /* border-right:2px solid black; */

                        }

                         .navbar {
                          background:#4287f5;
                               }

                           body {
                           font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
                           /* font-weight:700; */
                            }

                          .navbar-nav li a {
                           color: #FFFFFF;
                           font-size:20px;
                              }
```

Comment: There is a hamburger just the same background as the blue menu;)
Click on the right side and the menu will slide apart.
Add code such as this code and you will see that it exists there - `.navbar-toggler {
   background: red;
}`

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: hamburger is an image which was loaded with `.navbar-dark` theme. Maybe you have removed that class so that image is not showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using an image hamburger, create hamburger using HTML and CSS.

```css
.navbar, .navbar-nav {
  background: #4287f5;
}
.navbar-brand.custom {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 25px
}
.navbar-toggler {
  padding: .25rem .5rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: .25rem;
}
.navbar-togglebar {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 2px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 5px;
}
.navbar-nav li a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  <a class="navbar-brand custom" href="#">Jesse</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-togglebar"></span>
    <span class="navbar-togglebar"></span>
    <span class="navbar-togglebar"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About me <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact me</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following styling to the navigation burger icon:

```css
/*Initial burger state*/
button.navbar-toggler.navbar-dark.collapsed {
    background: #000;
}

/*When toggled*/
.navbar-toggler:not(:disabled):not(.disabled) {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #000;
}
```